# In Argo WorkflowTemplates, how to manipulate the name of the resulting Workflow?

Tags: argo-workflows

In Argo Workflows, when I am developing a `WorkflowTemplate` to be used to submit workflow runs from the web UI, how do I programmatically set what name will be assigned to the `Workflow`?

In particular, can I somehow resolve the values of `{{workflow.parameters.xxxx}}` and append that to the prefix used to generate a unique name for the workflow run? This would let me make the names (of the many distinct individual runs) far more descriptive and useful. Or is this not possible?